# Spark DataFrameWriter uses TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, mariadb

I am migrating my database from SQL Server to MariaDB, but I'm running into trouble with MariaDB's TIMESTAMP range limit.

I have a PySpark project that populates the database, creating tables using DataFrameWriter.jdbc() in overwrite mode. WHen working with SQL Server, Spark turns its own Timestamp datatype into SQL Server's DATETIME2 datatype, which works just fine. However, when working with MariaDB, it turns it into MariaDB's own TIMESTAMP, which has a range that ends in the year 2038. This causes trouble for all those tables containing values greater than that.

I know that MariaDB has a DATETIME type, which shares the same range as SQL Server's DATETIME, but I can't find a way to force Spark to use that data type when creating the table.

I also can't create the table manually, because it's supposed to be recreated every time my scripts run.

Comment: A database that has a time range limit? Are you sure?

Comment: Maybe try casting to string on spark side and convert to datetime on db side

Comment: @sramalingam24: Yes, you can take a look at the MariaDB Knowledge Base as well: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestamp/. Storing the data as a string would avoid the script from crashing, but I'd rather have a datetime data type. I guess it's something I could do if there's no better way to force that...

Comment: @sramalingam24 - Are you suggesting that every database should be able to handle the year 10000?  I suspect most stop at 9999.  And what about a big negative number for the time of the Big Bang?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, when tr so instead of directly using spark.read/write with jdbc I established a connection by using mysql.connection package. Here a look:

```
!pip install mysql.connector
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",port=3306, user="root", password="yourpassword", database="xyz")
cursor = conn.cursor()
Qry = "create table TempTableMaria (colA VARCHAR(50), startdate datetime(6), enddate datetime(6), colB VARCHAR(50));"
cursor.execute(Qry)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

You can pass a cutomized create table query where you can specify the columns and their data type as per requirement and create an empty table with required schema.

Once you are done with your job, you can always drop the table if you need so.

For rest of the operations such as append/overwrite this table you can always go back to the df.write.format("jdbc").... When you write to this table now, your timestamp datatype of dataframe will be stored as datetime and no issues will occur if your column contains a date of 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000000

Hope this helps!